# Fetch associated models after fetching the Model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, model-associations

I have a model "Task". One Task belongs to exactly one User and one User has many Tasks. So this is a one to many relation. Now I can fetch User with their Task as follows.

```
User.findByPk(41, {include: [Task]});
```

But I don't want to fetch Task while fetching user. Instead I would like to fetch Task something like.

```
var user = await User.findByPk(41);    
var tasks = await user.load(Task);
```

Is there any method provided by Sequelize models to load the associations later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an association generates a getter for that association on the model, therefore you can retrieve the associated Tasks like so:

```
var user = await User.findByPk(41);
var tasks = await user.getTasks();
```

Source: [Official documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#associating-objects)